# AWK - sum plus and minus values into separate variables

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a `CSV` file like this:

```
2019.04.15;3.75;
2019.04.29;-5.17;
2019.05.01;7.5;
2019.05.06;0.5;
2019.05.13;0.25;
2019.05.20;-8.5;
```

I want to get the sum of the `plus` and the `minus` values off the second column.

I solved this with the following `pipe` using `awk` and `grep`:

```
plus=$(awk -F';' '{print $2};' "$file" |
      grep --invert-match "-" |
      awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
)

minus=$(awk -F';' '{print $2};' "$file" |
      grep "-" |
      awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}'
)
```

I'm pretty sure `awk` can do it on his own, by using one command, the question is how would it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plus:

```
awk -F';' '$2~/^[^\-]/{s+=$2} END{print s}'  data
```

minus:

```
awk -F';' '$2~/^[\-]/{s+=$2} END{print s}'  data
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ set -f; IFS=" " 
$ set $(perl -F\; -lane '$A[$F[1]<0] += $F[1]}{print "@A"' "$file") 
$ plus=$1 minus=$2
```

Answer (score 1):

One more `awk` solution:

```
awk -F\; 'BEGIN {plus=0;minus=0} 
{if ($2>0) plus+=$2; else minus+=$2; } 
END {minus=-minus; print plus minus}' input_filename
```

Comment: I get:`awk: cmd. line:2: {if ($2>0) plus+=$2 else minus+=$2}
awk: cmd. line:2:                                          ^ syntax error` when using this as script.

Comment: @nath, will correct it shortly

Comment: nice one, cheers <3